# magento 1.9,when i create custom module both the frontend and backend gives a 404 error

Tags: magento-1.9

*magento 1.9,when i create custom module both the frontend and backend gives a 404 error, and as soon as i remove those custom files everything goes back to normal*

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Fruit_Apple>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Fruit_Apple>
    </modules>
</config>

    //controller file
    <?php
class Fruit_Apple_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{
    public function indexAction(){
        echo "I am visible!";
    }
}
?>

    //config file
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Fruit_Apple>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Fruit_Apple>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <apple>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Fruit_Apple</module>
                    <frontName>apple</frontName>
                </args>
            </apple>
            </apple>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found what's wrong,actually magento 1.9 doesn't support my php version.